# Loop through array with setInterval play button and pause it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to loop through a array with a pause and a start button. Right now it automatically plays and I am not sure how to connect the setInterval to the play function and not sure how to stop the interval as everything I try just crashes it. Maybe there is a good a library for doing this as I can imagine this is quite a normal thing to do? If not please help me fix my code, maybe there is better ways to do this if so please tell :)
Codesandbox attempt: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-dream-4kldkg?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7];
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const play = () => {
    setCurrent(current + 1);
  };
  const pause = () => {};
  const reset = () => {
    setCurrent(0);
  };
  var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
    if (current >= array.length) {
      setCurrent(0);
    }
    setCurrent(current + 1);
  }, 5000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => play()}>play</button>
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={() => pause()} style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}>
        Pause
      </button>
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={() => reset()} style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}>
        Reset
      </button>
      <br></br>
      <h1>{array[current]}</h1>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you need to clearInterval(intervalId) in reset

Comment: and in pause function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the interval on each render, please see the demo:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(true);
  const play = () => {
    setPaused(false);
  };
  const resume = () => {
    setPaused(false);
  };
  const pause = () => {
    setPaused(true);
  };
  const reset = () => {
    setCurrent(0);
    setPaused(true);
  };

  useEffect(
    function () {
      var timeout;
      if (!paused) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          const next = current < array.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
          setCurrent(next);
        }, 1000);
      }
      return function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      };
    },
    [paused, current, array.length]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => play()}>play</button>
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={() => pause()} style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}>
        Pause
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => resume()} style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}>
        Resume
      </button>
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={() => reset()} style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}>
        Reset
      </button>
      <br></br>
      <h1>{array[current]}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cdn-4c77nr